# Gmail search for specific threads using listUsersThreads() query to filter colored stars

Tags: php, colors, fetch, gmail-api

I have discovered that in the listUsersThreads() function in the PHP gmail library one can use (l:(^ss_sp|^ss_co)) in the query to find purple star/orange icon thanks to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/6cTJF4rrTng;context-place=topicsearchin/gmail/authorid$3AAPn2wQfpf2FkIyVi3XdoU_Sj9nUVfmCCbQLUIUEeGZbhrIwHz6QlPvhta04naGBrir-jzlxbYV1C%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list?authuser=2

I would like to some how include the thread ID in this query so that I can detect which threads are a certain color when importing them into my system. I could use a combination of subject, sender, recipients to narrow the search but I would rather not do it that way. If I could do it with the threadID that would be great.

Still no way (to my knowledge) of updating the coloured stars but I am sure that will come eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Currently supported, you can only add or remove `labelId` in modifying a specific thread. With [`Users.threads: modify`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify?authuser=2), simply send a HTTP request with the following format:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/threads/id/modify
```

You need to first obtain the `threadId` using [`Users.threads: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) with `q` parameter value of `is:starred` for starred messages as discussed in this [page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

In updating the colored stars, you may want to search or request for [missing features](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support#missing_features).